# Is it possible to give a cell a different value than it displays?

Tags: google-sheets

What I mean by this is maybe explained easiest with an example:

I habe a list of items and every item has a name and an ID.
I want to sort that list by ID, with the exception to have item "XYZ" with ID 24 alwas on first place. So I would like to give it's ID-cell the value 0 (for sorting) but it should still show the value 24.

Sounds weird and is probably not possible?

Edit: I want it to look like this:

[image]

If the user is sorting (using the filter drop down menu) by ID column, it should be sorted as it's in this picture.
I found a solution for the first ID (Hans): Custom number format for that cell:"0;0;"24". It will show the value 0 as '24'. That doesn't help for Franz tho. Here I want a value between 5 and 7 showed as '??'.

Comment: share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output

Comment: not weird, just a common practice, totally possible.

Comment: @player0 I added a screenshot and more description and a part of a elegant solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution (with a little help):
For only the cells you want to show "Something else" but be handled as the values, edit the *Custom number format* to:

[image]

By this, it will always show what you put in there, no matter what value the cell has.

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution would be creating a second ID and sorting the values based on this new ID. Something like this:

[image]

Comment: Thing is, I want to use 'filter' as in your example. But i don't want the user to see the 'wrong' ID2.

Answer (score 0):

If you are sorting through formula in other columns you can use:

```
=SORT(A2:B,MAP(B2:B,LAMBDA(id,IF(id=24,0,id))),1)
```

[image]

Comment: I want the user to be able to sort it using the filter function. he should not see the "wrong" ID. I edited the question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Exclude that first item from sorting then merge again. Try the following formula.

```
={A1:B2;SORT(A3:B,2,1)}
```

[image]

Comment: I want the user to be able to sort it using the filter function. he should not see the "wrong" ID. I edited the question accordingly.

Comment: you can't, the default filter has very limited functionality

Comment: I found a solution and answered my question

Answer (score 0):

[image]

1. Built an array youself for sorting with `IF(A1:A7=24,0,A1:A7)`, so that `XYZ` will have its weight as `0`,
2. place it next to your data as the 3rd column with `{}`,
3. use `QUERY()` to sort the data and get rid of the 3rd column.

Formula:

```
=ArrayFormula(
 QUERY({A1:B7,IF(A1:A7=24,0,A1:A7)},
  "Select Col1,Col2 Order By Col3 ASC",
 1)
)
```

Comment: I want the user to be able to sort it using the filter function. he should not see the "wrong" ID. I edited the question accordingly.